# call a control in the parent page from the built-page view (son) Xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have an application with the main page called MainWeb within one stackLayout I incorporate the view.
E 'can be called the "menuStack" control located in MainWeb.xaml from view Home.xaml son?

MainWeb.xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="YourListViewStackLayout" BackgroundColor="Green">
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start">
   <!--top controls--> 
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Padding="15" BackgroundColor="#0084CA">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="42"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Image Aspect="AspectFit" x:Name="menuImageButton" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/menu.png"></Image>
      <Image Aspect="AspectFit" x:Name="nearImageButton" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/near.png"></Image>
    </Grid>   
</StackLayout>   
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <ScrollView>                   
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="downContent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="15">
        <!--child incorporate here-->
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

i do call downContent control from view child.

I need to take the height of the stackLayout.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you are trying to do? Do you want to embed another xaml control that you created inside the page, where it says "child incorporate here" ?

Comment: i wish call control in father xaml page from view xaml page, how to get parent name control ?

Comment: each control has property Parent. Cast it to appropriate class and call what you need

Comment: how to cast parent class ?